# How to suppress caption numbering in a table?

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

How can the auto-numbering on table captions be suppressed? For example, I have a table:

```
\section{Data}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5px}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc} \bottomrule 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is my caption.}
\end{table}
```

I just want the caption to read `This is my caption.` However, when I compile this code into a PDF file my table is automatically named `Table 1. This is my caption.` I've tried using `\caption*`, to suppress the auto-generated `Table 1.`, but this does not solve my problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: `\caption*` should do the job (if the `caption` package has been loaded). Can you please post a (complete) [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) showing the problem?

Comment: @dr.bunsen: What exactly do you mean by "this does not solve my problem"? What happens? Furthermore your code snipped does not even contain `\caption*` so how should it show us the problem?

Comment: Thanks, for the help - this solved my problem. My problem was that I was not importing the caption package. I didn't realize that I needed to import this package since my table was displaying a caption without importing this package.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can suppress the caption label in saveral ways using features provided by the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package:

1. Using `\caption*` instead of `\caption`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{caption}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{table}[h]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{c} 
       text1\\
       text2
     \end{tabular}
     \caption*{This is my caption.}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Using the option `labelformat=empty` for `\captionsetup`.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{caption}

   \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{table}[h]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{c} 
       text1\\
       text2
     \end{tabular}
     \caption{This is my caption.}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
   ```

Since I used `table` as optional argument for `\captionsetup`, this change will only affect the `table` environments; of course, you can use `figure` instead (to affect only the `figure` environment), or no optional argument at all, which means that the change will affect all your floating objects.

Also, as I used `\captionsetup` in the preamble, the change will affect all the (in this case) `table` environments in your document; if you want the change to affect only a particular table environment, you can use

```
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
```

inside that particular `table` environment.

The result after compilation of any of my example codes is

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use the [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to control the look and feel of the captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\section{Data}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}  
...table content...
\end{tabular}
\caption*{This is my caption.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `memoir` class (caters for the `book`, `report`, and `article` classes) incudes the `\legend` macro

```
\legend{text}
```

which can be used to put an anonymous caption, or legend, into a float environment but it can be used anywhere, such as in a marginal note.

See section *Continuation captions and legends* in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`)